# Updating UITextField.text when hitting button - swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I define my UITextField, and call it in my viewDidLoad function. From there I also call a UIButton that when pressed it reads the value of the text field as 'print(myTextField.text!). If I change the value in the text field again and hit the button, the value of myTextField.text! is still the same as before. Here is my text field and here is my button, im not sure how to implement an update call. My question is how can I read the updated value and why doesn't it update in the first place?

```
let myTextField: UITextField = {
    let UTextFieldDesign = UITextField()
    UTextFieldDesign.textColor = .black
    return UTextFieldDesign
}()
let loginButton: UIButton = {
    let LButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    LButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
    LButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    LButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Check Text", comment: ""), for: .normal)
    LButton.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    LButton.backgroundColor = LoginButtonColor
    LButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loginAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    return LButton
}()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTap()
    setupMyTextField() //this just adds the constraints
    setupLoginButton() 

@objc func loginAction() {
    print(myTextField.text!)
}


fileprivate func setupMyTextField() {

    view.addSubview(myTextField)
    myTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    myTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    myTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
}

fileprivate func setupLoginButton() {
    view.addSubview(loginButton)
    loginButton.anchors(top: myTextField.bottomAnchor, topPad: 15, bottom: nil, bottomPad: 0,
                        left: view.leftAnchor, leftPad: 20, right: view.rightAnchor,
                        rightPad: -20, height: 50, width: 0)
    loginButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}
```

Comment: where is the update value happen in the label

Comment: can you please write the whole code ?

Comment: Updated the code

Comment: @kjoe I was hoping I could enter "hey" in the text field when the app is running and hit the button and in console it prints "hey" and then I can change it to say "you" and when I hit the button it prints "you" but instead it always prints "hey"

Comment: i don't see anyway the logic behind change textfield text in some place you must say myTextfield.text = "you", but iont see it, so how do you expect this happens.

Comment: because when I run the app I get a text field and I physically type it in when the app is running every time

Comment: Try setting the class as UITextFieldDelegate and use the func named textFieldDidEndEditing where you could save the text value to some local variable which then you will be able to call in your loginAction(). And don’t forget to set your class as a delegate of text field: myTextField.delegate = self